# Is it possible to use parent provider in child directives in angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to use a service as provider for general use in a Directive instead a Component. but it complains that it is not getting the service in the child Directive. I expected to use the service in the directive:

```
// CurrentTimeService.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class CurrentTimeService {
  dt: number;

  constructor() {
    this.dt = new Date().getTime();
  }


}

app.ts
//our root app component
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {CurrentTimeService} from "./CurrentTimeService"
import {SimpleDirective} from "./SimpleDirective"

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [CurrentTimeService],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 mySimpleDirective>Hello {{name}}</h2>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: [SimpleDirective]
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
  }
}

SimpleDirective.ts
import {Directive} from '@angular/core';
import { CurrentTimeService  } from "./currentTimeService"

@Directive({
    selector: '[mySimpleDirective]'
})
export class SimpleDirective {
  constructor(private currentTimeService: CurrentTimeService) {


  }

  /*
  uncomment this command, it is working because it doesn't demand the service
  constructor() { }
  */

}
```

You could check the plunker to look out the complete program: https://plnkr.co/edit/s0zUkI?p=preview

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong `import` statement in the SimpleDirective.ts. Change this

```
import { CurrentTimeService  } from "./currentTimeService"
```

to

```
import { CurrentTimeService  } from "./CurrentTimeService"
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ViGPbr?p=preview)